# Opposite of Behind schedule

Tags: word-choice, word-request, difference

What is the opposite of 'Behind the schedule?. How to say if we are ahead of the schedule or exactly on  the schedule?

Can I say we are ahead of schedule or on the schedule?

Comment: If you're ***on** schedule* you expect to finish ***at the planned time***. If you're ***ahead of*** schedule you expect to finish ***before*** then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Only thing is, don't use a "the".

The most common uses are:

*We are way behind schedule!*

*We are right on schedule!*

*We are well ahead of schedule!*